# Spaces inserted by the C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose we are given this input C code:

```
#define Y 20
#define A(x) (10+x+Y)

A(A(40))
```

`gcc -E` outputs like that `(10+(10+40 +20)+20)`.

`gcc -E -traditional-cpp` outputs like that `(10+(10+40+20)+20)`.

Why the default cpp inserts the space after `40` ?

Where can I find the most detailed specification of the cpp that covers that logic ?

Comment: Out of interest -- why does it matter to you?

Comment: to compare my own implementation with gcc's.

Comment: @alinsoar you can lex the two outputs and compare the resulting sequences of tokens.

Comment: it does not specify, but when you preprocess complicated data, like that from the Xv6/linux/etc kernel, you need to understand that logic, otherwise the upper preprocessing levels (5,6) may go wrong.  I want to see the general logic why that is important.  The Standard has lots of pitfalls, some of them were corrected via DRs, some not... etc

Comment: "Where can I find the most detailed specification of the cpp that covers that logic ?" - Asking for documentation, etc. is off-topic. But you should read the standard.

Comment: If it is not specified in the standard and it matters, then the behaviour is undefined. The only case I can think of where it would matter is in stringification, so I put that into an answer.

Comment: @rici: I would be careful with that. The C standard is quite clear about how to process the input during the preprocessing phase. IIRC, it also requires intermediate spaces to be inserted at certain points.

Comment: Olaf, as you see, this problem is out of specification.  You can see it as a pitfall in Standard.

Comment: @alinsoar: "implementation defined" is not a pitfall (do you mean a defect?) in the standard, but exactly what it says. So you haver to check the implementation for details.

Comment: The Standard really does not clearly explain the algorithm. You need to discover alone what is wrong with such or such implementation, etc.

Comment: @rici: But the standard also requires an implementation to speficy the behaviour.

Comment: I didn't even think that macros were nestable.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, macros are nestable, both in the sense that macro invocations may appear as or in macro arguments, and in the sense that macro invocations can appear in a macro's replacement text.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: But in a replacement list, the names of macros currently being replaced are not eligible for replacement. In that sense, expansions cannot be nested.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you, my comment should have said "recursive" or possibly "self-referencing".

Comment: @WeatherVane: right, but `A(40)` is not being fully expanded *with the replacement list* of the first `A`; it is fully expanded before being inserted. Contrast with `#define A(x,y) x y` `A(A,(40,60))` where the expansion of `A(40,60)` doesn't happen because it is in the context of the rescan.

Comment: @olaf: The standard only requires the implementation to specify how it handles unspecified behaviour in terms of the execution of the program. Specification is not required for warnings, compiler debugging output, or other products which happen to be produced by the compiler but are not related to program execution. The output of `gcc -E` falls into one of the latter two categories, perhaps both of them, but is in no way in the scope of the standard.

Comment: @rici: No, an implementation is not required to specify _unspecified behaviour_ per se. But it is required to specify _implementation defined behaviour_ (3.4.1) which is an explicit sub-cathegory of unspecified-behaviour. And some parts of preprocessing are implementation-defined. If I knew fully, I'd provide an answer, it is just that there is a clear difference between standard-compliant preprocessing and pre-standard.

Comment: @Olaf: yes, but again that doesn't apply to `gcc -E`.

Comment: If it is any help, `clang` (as found in XCode on Mac OS X) generates the space for both `-traditional` and not `-traditional`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler --  The CPP, V3 does not guarantee either that pre-standard features still always work.  Quote from cpp-manual, v3: ``Traditional (pre-standard) C preprocessing is rather different from the preprocessing specified by the standard. When GCC is given the ‘-traditional’ option, it attempts to emulate a traditional preprocessor. We do not guarantee that GCC’s behavior under ‘-traditional’ matches any pre-standard preprocessor exactly.``

Comment: *Where can I find the most detailed specification of the cpp that covers that logic ?*  What?   `cpp` is a different programming language from `c`

Comment: @user3629249: correct. preprocessing phases of the C language (stages 1->6) compose together a completely different programming language from C, but there are some common aspects between them, as the output of one is an input for the other. cpp is a language that is defined by substitution (like in lambda calculus model of computation) while C makes computations using the pointer model, close of a turing machine model of computation. (See the B and BCPL original papers, where you can find C and the model of computation that C uses, without preprocessing and without type check).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The C standard doesn't specify this behaviour, since the output of the preprocessing phase is simply a stream of tokens and whitespace. Serializing the stream of tokens back into a character string, which is what `gcc -E` does, is not required or even mentioned by the standard, and does not form part of the translation processs specified by the standard.

In phase 3, the program "is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters." Aside from the result of the concatenation operator, which ignores whitespace, and the stringification operator, which preserves whitespace, tokens are then fixed and whitespace is no longer needed to separate them. However, the whitespace is needed in order to:

- parse preprocessor directives
- correctly process the stringification operator

The whitespace elements in the stream are not eliminated until phase 7, although they are no longer relevant after phase 4 concludes.

Gcc is capable of producing a variety of information useful to programmers, but not corresponding to anything in the standard. For example, the preprocessor phase of the translation can also produce dependency information useful for inserting into a Makefile, using one of the `-M` options. Alternatively, a human-readable version of the compiled code can be output using the `-S` option. And a compilable version of the preprocessed program, roughly corresponding to the token stream produced by phase 4, can be output using the `-E` option. None of these output formats are in any way controlled by the C standard, which is only concerned with actually executing the program.

In order to produce the `-E` output, gcc must serialize the stream of tokens and whitespace in a format which does not change the semantics of the program. There are cases in which two consecutive tokens in the stream would be incorrectly glued together into a single token if they are not separated from each other, so gcc must take some precautions. It cannot actually insert whitespace into the stream being processed, but nothing stops it from adding whitespace when it presents the stream in response to `gcc -E`.

For example, if macro invocation in your example were modified to

```
A(A(0x40E))
```

then naive output of the token stream would result in

```
(10+(10+0x40E+20)+20)
```

which could not be compiled because `0x40E+20` is a single pp-number token which cannot be converted into a numeric token. The space before the `+` prevents this from happening.

If you attempt to implement a preprocessor as some kind of string transformation, you will undoubtedly confront serious issues in the corner cases. The correct implementation strategy is to tokenize first, as indicated in the standard, and then perform phase 4 as a function on a stream of tokens and whitespace.

Stringification is a particularly interesting case where whitespace affects semantics, and it can be used to see what the actual token stream looks like. If you stringify the expansion of `A(A(40))`, you can see that no whitespace was actually inserted:

```
$ gcc -E -x c - <<<'
#define Y 20
#define A(x) (10+x+Y)
#define Q_(x) #x
#define Q(x) Q_(x)         
Q(A(A(40)))'

"(10+(10+40+20)+20)"
```

The handling of whitespace in stringification is precisely specified by the standard: (§6.10.3.2, paragraph 2, many thanks to John Bollinger for finding the specification.)

> Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens
>   becomes a single space character in the character string literal. White space before the first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token composing the argument is deleted.

Here is a more subtle example where additional whitespace is required in the `gcc -E` output, but is not actually inserted into the token stream (again shown by using stringification to produce the real token stream.) The `I` (identify) macro is used to allow two tokens to be inserted into the token stream without intervening whitespace; that's a useful trick if you want to use macros to compose the argument to the `#include` directive (not recommended, but it can be done).

Maybe this could be a useful test case for your preprocessor:

```
#define Q_(x) #x
#define Q(x) Q_(x)
#define I(x) x
#define C(x,...) x(__VA_ARGS__)
// Uncomment the following line to run the program
//#include <stdio.h>

char*quoted=Q(C(I(int)I(main),void){I(return)I(C(puts,quoted));});
C(I(int)I(main),void){I(return)I(C(puts,quoted));}
```

Here's the output of gcc -E (just the good stuff at the end):

```
$ gcc -E squish.c | tail -n2
char*quoted="intmain(void){returnputs(quoted);}";
int main(void){return puts(quoted);}
```

In the token stream which is passed out of phase 4, the tokens `int` and `main` are not separated by whitespace (and neither are `return` and `puts`). That's clearly shown by the stringification, in which no whitespace separates the token. However, the program compiles and executes fine, even if passed explicitly through `gcc -E`:

```
$ gcc -E squish.c | gcc -x c - && ./a.out 
intmain(void){returnputs(quoted);}
```

and compiling the output of `gcc -E`.

---

Different compilers and different versions of the same compiler may produce different serializations of a preprocessed program. So I don't think you will find any algorithm which is testable with a character-by-character comparison with the `-E` output of a given compiler.

The simplest possible serialization algorithm would be to unconditionally output a space between two consecutive tokens. Obviously, that would output unnecessary spaces, but it would never syntactically alter the program.

I think the minimal space algorithm would be to record the DFA state at the end of the last character in a token so that you can later output a space between two consecutive tokens if there exists a transition from the state at the end of the first token on the first character of the following token. (Keeping the DFA state as part of the token is not intrinsically different from keeping the token type as part of the token, since you can derive the token type from a simple lookup from the DFA state.) That algorithm would not insert a space after `40` in your original test case, but it would insert a space after `0x40E`. So it is not the algorithm being used by your version of gcc.

If you use the above algorithm, you will need to rescan tokens created by token concatenation. However, that is necessary anyway, because you need to flag an error if the result of the concatenation is not a valid preprocessing token.

If you don't want to record states (although, as I said, there is essentially no cost in doing so) and you don't want to regenerate the state by rescanning the token as you output it (which would also be quite cheap), you could precompute a two-dimensional boolean array keyed by token type and following character. The computation would essentially be the same as the above: for every accepting DFA state which returns a particular token type, enter a true value in the array for that token type and any character with a transition out of the DFA state. Then you can look up the token type of a token and the first character of the following token to see if a space may be necessary. This algorithm does not produce a minimally-spaced output: it would, for example, put a space after the `40` in your example, since `40` is a `pp-number` and it is possible for some `pp-number` to be extended with a `+` (even though you cannot extend `40` in that way). So it's possible that gcc uses some version of this algorithm.

Comment: I would be careful with that. The C standard is quite clear about how to process the input during the preprocessing phase. IIRC, it also requires intermediate spaces to be inserted at certain points.

Comment: Why do you think the gnu developers made the effort to insert spaces -- this is the main point.  I start from the idea they wanted to correct some possible bugs in upper processing levels, etc.

Comment: @alinsoar: I presume it was to avoid accidentally outputing two consecutive tokens which might get glued together. For example, if `x` had been `0x1e`, then the space would be necessary in order to be able to round-trip. But internally, it would just be a sequence of tokens.

Comment: OK, did you find some relevant documentation about this issue ?

Comment: @alinsoar: It's not an issue. I'll add a little more to my answer.

Comment: I think you've hit the key point very clearly: there is no whitespace at all in the preprocessor's output.  The output is a sequence of tokens.  `gcc -E` gives a human-readable representation of the token stream, but it should not be confused with the preprocessor's output as consumed by the compiler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I tried to make that as clear as possible in my answer but perhaps it could be clearer. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer, but please post here some relevant entries in Technical corrigendum or something similar if you find. Thanks again.

Comment: @alinsoar: As I said, *the output of gcc -E is not subject to the standard*, and the standard does not propose a preprocessing algorithm on character strings. So there is no issue to be resolved by the standard (possibly aside from the precise handling of whitespace during stringification; I don't recall ever having seen anything related to that, but I'll look again when I get the chance.)

Comment: @rici, I couldn't put it clearer myself, except with respect to stringification.  The standard is specific here: "Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character string literal.  White space before the
first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token composing the argument is deleted."  Note that this does distinguish between preprocessing tokens that are separated by whitespace and those that are not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thanks. Editing.

Comment: Macro expansion happens in the 4th stage; the #( stringification ) and ## ( token-concatenation) operators are executed in the same stage as these space insertions. After that stage only string concat ; convertion of preprocessing tokens into C tokens and elimination of blank tokens remain to be completed.

Comment: @alinsoar: That's correct. There is no definition of what, exactly, the preprocessor is, but as it happens `gcc -E` captures the output at the end of phase 4. (I think; I've never checked to see if it does phase 5.) The standard does not require the existence of a separate "preprocessor", nor does it even suggest that such a thing exist although many historic implementations do work that way. I'm not sure what you mean by "space insertion" here: the only place spaces are inserted is in phase 3, where comments are replaced by a single space.

Comment: `gcc -E` does not capture adjacent strings concatenation operation.

Comment: rici: `space insertion` is about the spaces you see when you run `gcc -E`. The Standard requires to remove trailing blanks, but gcc inserts trailing whitespaces sometimes, as in my example.

Comment: @alinsoar: As I've said now various times, the `-E` output is not subject to the standard. Neither is `-S` output. Nor for that matter `-M*`. These are just things gcc does as a favour to programmers. It does not insert whitespace into the stream of tokens and whitespace produced by phase 3: that should be clear by examining the stringification example, where no whitespace has been inserted. As with `gcc -S`, the output of `gcc -E` is a human-readable view of an internal data structure.

Comment: Which is exactly what @JohnBollinger said more concisely a few comments up :)

Comment: As I said, I suspect the developers discovered something very subtle about preprocessing, this is why they decided to insert that space sometimes, not just to look pretty, my belief...  anyway, if something goes wrong I will discover later.  Do you know some unit tests for cpp ?

Comment: @alinsoar: Do you not find my explanation convincing (the `0x1E` example)? Or John Bollinger's example of two consecutive plus or minus signs? I'm certain that is why the spaces are inserted *in the `gcc -E` output* (but not in the token stream itself). There are a few tests in the tinycc repository (http://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git/tree/HEAD:/tests/pp) and there are probably tests in libclang.

Comment: rici, Yes, Quite so. This is why I accepted the answer. Because your answer seems to be _one_ of the reasons.  Maybe there are others, who knows?

Comment: @alinsoar: Another corner case occurred to me, so I added it to the end of the answer.

Comment: @rici, could you write a full algorithm that inserts trailing whitespaces each time when necessary ?

Comment: @alinsoar: I added a brief discussion of algorithms at the end of the answer, although I really feel that this is getting out of scope of the original question, and that you should ask a different question if you want to explore the issue further.

Answer (score 4):

Adding some historical context to rici's excellent answer.

If you can get your hands on a working copy of gcc 2.7.2.3, experiment with its preprocessor.  At that time the preprocessor was a separate program from the compiler, and it used a *very* naive algorithm for text serialization, which tended to insert far more spaces than were necessary.  When Neil Booth, Per Bothner and I implemented the integrated preprocessor (appearing in gcc 3.0 and since), we decided to make `-E` output a bit smarter at the same time, but without making the implementation too complicated.  The core of this algorithm is the library function `cpp_avoid_paste`, defined at https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libcpp/lex.c#l2990 , and its caller is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/c-family/c-ppoutput.c#l177 (look for "Subtle logic to output a space...").

In the case of your example

```
#define Y 20
#define A(x) (10+x+Y)
A(A(40))
```

`cpp_avoid_paste` will be called with a CPP_NUMBER token (what rici called a "pp-number") on the left, and a '+' token on the right.  In this case it unconditionally says "yes, you need to insert a space to avoid pasting" rather than checking whether the last character of the number token is one of eEpP.

Compiler design often comes down to a trade-off between accuracy and implementation simplicity.

Comment: Concerning the preprocessor, I am interested now about the full algorithm how it attaches the type for the constant lexemes -- for example int for `'a'`, wchar_t for `L'a'`, unsigned char for `'\x22'` etc.  Can you recommend me where to look to find out how gcc attaches types to input constants ?  Is there a detailed doc about how gcc type checks the C code ?

Comment: There's no such documentation, and there also isn't a cross-referenced online copy of the source as far as I know.  But the place to start reading code is `gcc/c-family/c-lex.c`, chasing function calls into `libcpp`.

Comment: Do you want me to open a new post about `algorithm to attach types to lexemes` ?  Would you be so kind to provide a detailed answer for  constant lexemes ?

Comment: The [GCC internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/), particularly the bits that talk about "GENERIC", "GIMPLE", and "trees", doesn't AFAIK address your question directly, but reading it will help you read the code.  The [CPP internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/) is mostly not relevant but it _does_ have a section talking about insertion of spaces in preprocessor output.

Comment: Your questions are verging on being so GCC-specific that they won't get good answers here because nobody knows the innards in enough detail (I used to know a lot, but that was 10 years ago); but if generalized, "How does a C compiler decide the types of numeric literals"? is likely to be dismissed with "go read a good book on C", as the algorithm is spelled out in the C standard. I suggest you take these questions to the `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` mailing list instead.  Be very clear that you are trying to read and understand the code.

Comment: It is good to know how to compare my results with the output from GCC and other C standard compilers.  Apart from that, my purpose is to understand the algorithm , if I understand an implementation, like GCC's, then I understand the general algo, etc.

Comment: I will download `gcc 2.7.2.3` and look at some aspects.  This idea may be good, to download even further, version 1.0, because the old versions may reveal the algorithms, as it is much less code to read.

Comment: Zack, all the old archives are available http://nl.mirror.babylon.network/gcc/old-releases/

Comment: I profit of your presence and I ask one more question -- do you know where can I find unit tests for a C compiler (including unit tests for cpp as well) ?

Comment: Old releases of GCC are simpler but they are also much more likely to be sloppy about things that we consider essential today.  I would not go back any further than 2.7.2.x.  And unfortunately *unit* test suites for C tend to cost enormous sums of money.  GCC has a large test suite but it's all integration / regression tests.

Comment: 1. I downloaded the 1st version, and that one was 10 years before `long long`, `restrict` to appear, indeed. However, it is instructive to read it as some ideas are clear, where the old Standard is still the same. 2. ``unit test suites for C tend to cost enormous sums of money``.  Ok, this is an interesting statement.  I rephrase so: Suppose you are writing your own  _full_ C99 compiler and want to test it. Suppose you find the best choice to use the gcc's tests.  How do you do it ?  The best and most direct way is to use unit tests, but, unfortunately cannot find. So?

Comment: GCC's test suite can only be run using GCC's test harness.  Picking that up and dropping it verbatim into the new compiler's source tree, and then sorting out all the tentacles it has into the build system, is the only way (or, more precisely, any other option would be nearly as much work as writing a test suite from scratch).

Comment: In this moment, in order to test, I use sed to cut all whitespaces from my output and compare using melt/diff. You say there is no way to extract GCC's tests and the correct outputs? Are they encoded using GCC internal structures ?

Comment: If you don't want to take my word for it, start reading the code! (gcc/testsuite)

Comment: I found lots of .c files here: gcc-5.3.0/gcc/testsuite/gcc.c-torture/execute.  I think to do a for x in *; do DIFF-COMPARE $(gcc $x) $(myout); done.  Do you think I could do better?  I tried to read the code from gcc, I cannot as I do not know where to start from.  I read only chunks.

Comment: anyway, putting in the environment of execution my own `abort` function, I could do something, etc.

Comment: If you don't know how to dig into a giant confusing poorly-documented source tree, now is the time to learn.  Alas, the only way to learn is by doing. I would offer advice, but it won't fit in the confines of the comment box, or even the answer box.  Again, your best bet for a roadmap is to talk to the people actually still involved in GCC development.

Comment: I will follow your advices.  I want first of all to possess my final tool.  After that I will need to import the tests, to be sure I did not work in vain.  For now, the gcc int. manual has +750 pages ;).