# How does preprocessing work in this snippet?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A -B
#define B -C
#define C 5

int main() {
  printf("The value of A is %dn", A); 
  return 0;
}
```

I came across the above code. I thought that after preprocessing, it gets transformed to

```
// code from stdio.h

int main() {
  printf("The value of A is %dn", --5); 
  return 0;
}
```

which should result in a compilation error. But, the code compiles fine and produces output `5`.

How does the code get preprocessed in this case so that it does not result into a compiler error?

PS: I am using gcc version 8.2.0 on Linux x86-64.

Comment: Take a look: https://godbolt.org/g/Rg2z8m It is transformed into  `- -5`. Note the space. Why? A good question. The answer is probably buried somewhere in the standard...

Comment: @EugeneSh. This seems like a good answer (as are a lot of your responses). Why don't you add them as answers?

Comment: @AlexJohnson Because I am digging in the standard to make it complete:) Probably will give up.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Fair enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your quick reply. I hope you get the complete answer soon. And thanks for letting me know about "Compiler Explorer" where I can test more of such code.

Comment: Looks like it might be a compiler-specific behavior, not a standard one. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/cpp-4.3-doc/cppinternals.html#Token-Spacing

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796947/spaces-inserted-by-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not sure, but I also think it is an implementation-dependent behaviour. Thanks for the excellent links.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It's compiler dependent.  MSVC produces `printf("The value of A is %dn", --5);` for the line in question.  I'd say this is GCC explicitly trying to prevent token pasting in this case.  If you change `B` to this: `#define B +C` the space magically vanishes and you get `...%d\n", -+5);` on godbolt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor is defined as operating on a stream of *tokens*, not text.  You have to read through all of sections [5.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1), [6.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4), and [6.10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10) of the C standard to fully understand how this works, but the critical bits are in 5.1.1.1 "Phases of translation": in phase 3, the source file is "decomposed into preprocessing tokens"; phases 4, 5, and 6 operate on those tokens; and in phase 7 "each preprocessing token is converted into a token".  That indefinite article is critical: each preprocessing token becomes *exactly one* token.

What this means is, if you start with this source file

```
#define A -B
#define B -C
#define C 5
A
```

then, after translation phase 4 (macro expansion, among other things), what you have is a sequence of three preprocessing tokens,

```
<punctuator: -> <punctuator: -> <pp-number: 5>
```

and at the beginning of translation phase 7 that becomes

```
TK_MINUS TK_MINUS TK_INTEGER:5
```

which is then parsed as the expression `-(-(5))` rather than as `--(5)`.  The standard offers no latitude in this: a C compiler that parses your example as `--(5)` is defective.

When you ask a compiler to dump out preprocessed source as text, the form of that text is not specified by the standard; typically, what you get has whitespace inserted as necessary so that a human will understand it the same way translation phase 7 would have.