# understanding a C Preprocessor Macro's output vs a line code

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define AD(x,y) (x+y)
int main()
{
    int x1=5,y1=2,z1;
    int x2=5,y2=2,z2;
    z1 = AD(x1,++y1);
    z2 = (x2+++y2) ;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x1,y1,z1);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x2,y2,z2);
}
```

why the output is different?
the first case is : 5 3 8
and the second is : 6 2 7

Comment: Yeah, you need to fix your broken code and then see where you are.

Comment: On another note, don't write code like this:  `z2=x2+++y2;` It's too difficult to read, and is prone to undefined behavior if you use too many + signs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Done

Comment: @RobertHarvey I dont think the undefined behavior applies in this case

Comment: It doesn't.  You still shouldn't write code this way.

Comment: You will have to look for new job right after something like this is submitted by you for a code review.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Come on.

Comment: Is there some compelling reason why the + signs are mashed together?  That wouldn't pass muster in any code review, at any company.

Comment: @user2422704 Seriously. People out there in the field don't do such a things. The first and the foremost priority of a code is its clarity. Well, not speaking of a classical macro pitfalls

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just wanted to understand deeply how the c preprocessor is working. it's not a code for a program

Comment: @user2422704 Sure, that's fine. Just be warned :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression

```
z2=x2+++y2;
```

is parsed by the compiler like

```
z2 = x2++ + y2;
```

From the C Standard (6.4 Lexical elements)

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
> a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest
> sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

So these tokens `+++` are parsed like `++` and `+`.
The expression with the macro

```
z1=AD(x1,++y1);
```

is parsed by the compiler like

```
z1 = x1 + ++y1;
```

The compiler already formed these sets of tokens `x1` and `++y1` due to the comma between the tokens.

So these two statements are different.

Comment: Is that true? The pre-preprocessor is supposed to do textural replacements, shouldn't the compiled code be identical? There are no spaces or parentheses.

Comment: But if macros are just "text replacement", as we often say, why would that affect how it is parsed? Wouldn't `AD(x1, ++y1)` simply result in `(x1+++y1)` at compilation phase?

Comment: @Blindy that exactly what i thought

Comment: Huh. Looking at the preprocessor output, I see `z1=(x1+ ++y1);`, even though there is no space in the macro definition or invocation. Interesting.

Comment: @FredLarson I saw different results with different compilers regarding adding spaces between output tokens, I think there was even a question about it.. but I doubt I will find it now

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, I was curious if different compilers might behave differently in this regard.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37796947/10077)?

Comment: @FredLarson: The `+` in the expansion is a distinct token from `x` and `y` in the replacement list, so it will stay a distinct token when `x` and `y` are expanded.

Comment: @fred: the preprocessor is not "text replacement". It is *token* replacement. The text has already been tokenised before the preprocessing phases, and what emerges from the preprocessor is a modified stream of tokens. Aside from the actions of the stringify and token concatenation operators (`#` and  `##`), every token in the output corresponds to an input token. The fact that some programs described as preprocessors produce a textual output, it's important to not be misled by that. Internally, the compiler is working on a token stream.