# Splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines: compilers produce different output

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Sample code (`t6.c`):

```
xxx \
#error
```

Invocations & output:

```
# on Windows
$ gcc -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E t6.c
xxx
 #error

# on Windows
$ clang -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E t6.c
xxx #error

# on Windows
$ cl /std:c11 /E t6.c
xxx \
t6.c(2): fatal error C1189: #error:

# on Linux
$ icc -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E t6.c
xxx #error
```

How the differences can be explained?

In my understanding:

- Clang and ICC are OK
- MSVC does not splice physical source lines to form logical source lines
- GCC may splice (so it does not find `#error` as MSVC does), but the logical source line (i.e. `xxx #error`) is not formed

Comment: Are you using windows for all of the above?   DOS derivatives have a messed up newline convention, which can rear its head in these cases.   The spurious CR (= 0xd) can be interpreted as the escaped character, preventing the lines from being joined.

Comment: Performing preprocessing only does not constitute a C implementation and is not covered by the C standard.

Comment: @mevets Yes, I use Windows for all of the above except ICC. Updated.

Comment: You can try converting your file to normal (LF-only), and the tests *should* be consistent.  The problem is that extra, or maybe expected CR, means it is really up to the particular app. As Eric helpfully pointed out, the standards are of no help.  Thankfully the physical world has a more rigourous requirement of its standards.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed. As user rici [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797110/1778275): "Serializing the stream of tokens back into a character string, which is what `gcc -E` does, is not required or even mentioned by the standard, and does not form part of the translation process specified by the standard".

Comment: @mevets At the 1st glance I expected to see that `-E` produces the code after splicing is done (i.e. `xxx #error`). However, the "preprocessing only" is out of scope of the C11. Another (interesting) note is that the C preprocessor is expected to work with preprocessing tokens. Meaning that in general you cannot "feed/process everything to/with the C preprocessor". In expects preprocessing tokens.